# What kind of amplifier to use?

Tags: led, voltage, amplifier

I'm driving an LED from the output of an optocoupler. Example, I'm trying to find surface errors on a sheet. When the sheet is flat the average output voltage is around 2.45V (based on the circuitry I made) so when ever there is a up or down on the surface of the sheet the Optocoupler varies from 2.20V (for depth in sheet) till 2.59V (for elevations). When I connect this to an LED I could see the changes in the intensity level for changes in the output **But... I have to turn off all the lights to see that change.**
I have tried to use a common emitter amplifier but that drives the LED too bright and I cannot see any changes in the intensity. Does anyone have any idea about how to solve this?

So what I exactly need is, except when the output voltage follows average value of 2.4V the rest of the cases when ever the value raises above 2.4V it should be amplified 2/3 times and once the output starts decreasing it should follow the same value or amplified less number of times compared to the value during the increment.

How do I do this? Do I need to use any micro-controller or any non-linear amplifier?

Comment: What about a circuit that turns on a green led when the voltage is in the "flat" range, and two red leds when out of range, one for depths and one for elevations?

Comment: that sounds good. but can that be attained without a microcontroller?

Comment: Yes sir! Search for "led vu meter", I'll be back soon

Comment: Another good search term is "window comparator".

Answer (score 1):

The eye is not very good at discerning changes in low levels of light intensity. A simple bridge circuit with an analog (centre zero) meter would provide you with a clear indication of amounts of up and down without the need for further amplification.

[image]

Depending on the meter used the value of VR2 should allow the meter to swing between 2.2 and 2,6.

R1, VR1 and R2 values (current about 1mA) would produce a mid voltage on VR2 of 2.45V which would zero the meter.